# How to segment a sequence of event by signal in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table of two fields 'order' and 'events', there are two types of events 'C' and 'S', I want to be able to segment/group rows by the onset of signal event 'S', ie, add a column "session" like below

```
order  event  session
1      C      1
2      C      1
3      C      1
4      S      1
5      C      2
6      S      2
7      C      3
8      C      3
9      S      3
```

can a SQL query do the job? Thanks.

Comment: Which is your database? MS sql server, oracle, MySql etc.?

Comment: if you sort `session asc` then this will work

Comment: sorry for the confusion. The original dataset only has 'order' and 'event', I want to add a column 'session' to group a subsequence of events ending with 'S'. So the first four events 'CCCS' is marked session 1, the next two events 'CS' is marked session 2, etc.

Comment: The data is in Google Bigquery, it is SQL like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is written in SQL Server syntax (for the table variable for the sample data) but it's fairly standard SQL and by looking at the [query reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference), I think it should run in BigQuery (once adapted to your actual table):

```
declare @t table ([order] int, event char(1))
insert into @t([order],event) values
(1,'C'),    (2,'C'),    (3,'C'),    (4,'S'),    (5,'C'),
(6,'S'),    (7,'C'),    (8,'C'),    (9,'S')

select
    t.*,
    s1.rn
from @t t
    inner join
(
select
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [order]) as rn
from
    @t
where
    event='S'
) s1
    on
        t.[order] <= s1.[order]
    left join
(
select
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [order]) as rn
from
    @t
where
    event='S'
) s2
    on
        t.[order] <= s2.[order] and
        s2.[order] < s1.[order]
where
    s2.[order] is null
```

I would have normally used a Common Table Expression (CTE) rather than duplicating the subquery for the `S` values, but I couldn't see whether that was supported.

The logic should be fairly straightforward to see - we number the `S` rows using a simple `ROW_NUMBER()` function, and then we match every row from the original table to the `S` row which most immediately succeeds it.

---

CTE variant (but, like I said, I couldn't see support for CTEs in the documentation):

```
declare @t table ([order] int, event char(1))
insert into @t([order],event) values
(1,'C'),    (2,'C'),    (3,'C'),    (4,'S'),    (5,'C'),
(6,'S'),    (7,'C'),    (8,'C'),    (9,'S')

;With Numbered as (
    select
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [order]) as rn
from
    @t
where
    event='S'
)
select
    t.*,
    s1.rn
from @t t
    inner join
Numbered s1
    on
        t.[order] <= s1.[order]
    left join
Numbered s2
    on
        t.[order] <= s2.[order] and
        s2.[order] < s1.[order]
where
    s2.[order] is null
```

Comment: Hi Damien, your first solution should be right. Unfortunately, BigQuery does not allow conditions other than equaling field names to be joined on. So I could add a dummy column of constant say "A", and t inner join s1 on t.dummy = s1.dummy where t.[order] <= s1.[order]. But for the left join, there is no null, I'm thinking of set difference, but there is NO 'EXCEPT' in bigquery either, I have to do the join again, which makes it awful. Any simpler way? Thanks.